# Looped If statements confusion - using scanners to find palindroms, cannot use .reverse for assignment

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

When I input any sentence, my output returns that any string is a palindrome, and I think that my replaceAll calls aren't working in some cases. This is likely due to error my part, because using the Scanner class in Java is new for me (more used to input from C++ and Python3). I added comments to make it clearer what my intentions were when writing the program.
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class PalindromeTest 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner stringScan = new Scanner(System.in);                            //Scanner for strings, avoids reading ints as strings
        Scanner intScan = new Scanner(System.in);                               //Scanner for ints, avoids reading strings as ints
        String forwardPal = "";                                                 //Variables for the rest of the program
        String reversePal = "";
        String trimForward = "";
        char tempChar;
        int revCount;
        int revPalLength;
        int quit;

        while (true)                                                            //Loop to keep the program running, problem is in here
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a word or a sentence.");           //Prompts user to enter a word or sentence, I assume that the program is counting
            forwardPal = stringScan.nextLine();

            trimForward = forwardPal.replaceAll(" " , "");                      //Trims the forwardPal string of characters that are not letters
            trimForward = trimForward.replaceAll("," , "");
            trimForward = trimForward.replaceAll("." , "");
            trimForward = trimForward.replaceAll("!", "");
            trimForward = trimForward.replaceAll(":", "");
            trimForward = trimForward.replaceAll(";", "");

            revPalLength = trimForward.length() ;                               //Makes the reverse palindrome length equal to the length of the new trimmed string entered
            for (revCount = revPalLength - 1; revCount >= 0; revCount--)        //Loop to count the reverse palindrome and add each character to the string reversePal iteratively
            {
                tempChar = trimForward.charAt(revCount);
                reversePal += tempChar;
                System.out.println(reversePal);
            }


            if (trimForward.equalsIgnoreCase(reversePal))                       //Makes sure that the palindrome forward is the same as the palindrome backwards
            {
                System.out.println("Congrats, you have a palindrome");          //Output if the sentence is a palindrome
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, that's not a palindrome");           //Output if the sentence isn't a palindrome
            }

            System.out.println("Press -1 to quit, any other number to enter another sentence.");    //Loops to ask if the user wants to continue
            quit = intScan.nextInt();                                                               //Checks if the user input a number
            if (quit == -1)                                                                         //If the user inputs -1, quit the program and close the strings
            {
                stringScan.close();
                intScan.close();
                break;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably would want to set reversePal back to an empty string in an else statement after your if statement. Otherwise, your program will continue to use the old response in your next run. Or make it a local varible within the loop as there is no reason for most of those variables to be declared global.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line

```
trimForward = trimForward.replaceAll("." , "");
```

That function takes the first argument as a regex, and the dot means that it is replacing all characters as a "".

Instead, use

```
trimForward = trimForward.replace("." , "");
```

In fact, all your lines should be using #replace instead of #replaceAll as none of them take advantage of regex. Only use those if you plan to take advantage of it.

Or in fact, if you do want to use a regex, this is a nice one which does all of that in one neat line.

```
trimForward = forwardPal.replaceAll("[ .!;:]" , "");
```

I hope this was of some help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to use [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) instead of [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

`replace()` replaces **all occurences** of the given *plain text*.
`replaceAll()` replaces all occurences of the given *regex*.

Since some of your replacements have special meaning in regex (specifically the dot `.`, which means any character), you cant use `replaceAll()` as you are currently (you'd have to escape the dot).

It's common, and quite reasonable, to assume that `replace()` replaces *one* occurrence and `replaceAll()` replaces *all* occurrences. They are poorly named methods, because they interpret their parameters differently, yet both replace all matches.

---

As an aside, you may find this briefer solution of interest:

```
forwardPal = forwardPal.replaceAll("\\W", ""); // remove non-word chars
boolean isPalindrome = new StringBuilder(forwardPal).reverse().toString().equals(forwardPal);
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer and another one worked, but I'm also having a problem when looping, because the strings aren't emptying, so it keeps adding characters to the `forwardPal` string. I added the statements: `forwardPal = "";`, but they haven't appeared to work.

Comment: @Josh sounds like a separate problem, which should be asked in a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).